# how to extract data from token

Tags: express, jwt

I am trying to set up a test to better understand how the jwt tokens work. I had set up a mock request and reponse here, and I can see in the console log that the console log the authorization header is passed and concistent. For testing pupouses I have also stored teh secret key as a static string ( I understand I should use an environment variable in pratice ). However when I compile and run, the token validation returns null. I'm at a loss for what I should do here, and several hours of serching the web have been fruitless.

I tried the follwing code and inserted the debug statements. Everything output as expected until the verify or decode.

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken'; // Import the sign function for generating JWT tokens


const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

//import dotenv = require('dotenv');

// get config vars
//dotenv.config();

// access config var

const jwtSecret: string = 'SecretKey'; // needs to be changed to environment variable in future

export function tokenExtractor(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log('req: ', req.headers);

    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log('verify before: ', jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret));
    console.log('decode2: ', jwt.decode(token));

    console.log('token: ', token);

    if(token) {
        console.log('secret: ', jwtSecret);

        console.log('verify: ', jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret));
        try {
            console.log('in try\n');
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
            console.log('set decoded');
            if (typeof decoded === 'object' && 'databaseName' in decoded) {
                req.app.locals.databaseName = decoded.databaseName;
            } else {
                throw new Error('Invalid token');
            }
        }catch (error) {
            console.log("invalid token from catch");
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' });
        }
    }else{
        console.log("not token");
    }
    // database name is used to login to a specific database on within teh atlas account
    next();
}

//const jwtSecret = 'SecretKey'; // Use the same secret key as in your tokenExtractor


console.log('secret: ', jwtSecret);
// Create a valid JWT token with a known value
const validToken = sign({ databaseName: 'YourDatabaseName' }, 'SecretKey', {
    expiresIn: 4 * 60 * 60, // 4 hours in seconds
  });
console.log('validToken: ', validToken);



const mockRequest: Request = {
    headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${validToken}`, // Include the token in the authorization header
    },
} as Request;
console.log('Authorization Header: ', mockRequest.headers.authorization);
const mockResponse: Response = {
    status: (code: number) => {
        return {
            json: (data: any) => {
                console.log(`Response Status Code: ${code}`);
                console.log('Response Data:', data);
            },
        };
    },
} as Response;

console.log('verify known valid: ', jwt.verify(validToken, jwtSecret));
//const decoded = jwt.verify(validToken, jwtSecret);

//console.log('Decoded Payload: ', decoded);

const mockNext: NextFunction = () => {
    console.log('Next function called.');
};

tokenExtractor(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockNext);
```

Comment: What does your header look like?

Comment: if I understand what you are asking, the output of the header is :



req:  {
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhYmFzZU5hbWUiOiJZb3VyRGF0YWJhc2VOYW1lIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk5MjM3Mzk5LCJleHAiOjE2OTkyNTE3OTl9.ikV9mGJ0TXqSMJOOlc4XgxgQqqQvoojmAT7BAR5u1-s'
}

Comment: It seems I needed to remove the 'Bearer; fromt the token to decode or auhthorize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the below code,

```
const mockRequest: Request = {
    headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${validToken}`, // Include the token in the authorization header
    },
} as Request;
```

it seems that you are passing the token in the `Authorization` request header with `Bearer`  in front of it.

In this line here, you are trying to decode the whole authorization header value that is also containing `Bearer`  instead of the token only.

```
const token = req.headers.authorization;
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
```

So maybe you should split the `Authorization` header value by `Bearer`  and get the second element of the split array.

```
const authorizationValue = req.headers.authorization; // Bearer mytoken
const token = authorizationValue.split("Bearer ")[1]; // mytoken

// Decode token...
```